# Uses previously logged in user's name on GitHub DeskTop OS X

Tags: git-commit, macos-mojave, github-desktop

I was logged in with my first User say A.

I signed out from that account and logged in with my User B. Now all my commits are being done with name A only.

All my preferences are set for User B. Even .gitignore file is set with User B. So what changes I need to do to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with git settings file. It didn't change with new user.

So I followed following commands,

$ git config user.email "email@example.com"
$ git config user.name "example name"

And also for globally i needed to change it so,

$ git config --global user.email "email@example.com"
$ git config --global user.name "example name"

This resolved my problem.